# Using Intellij for editing .js-files causes Jshint-errors

Tags: angularjs, intellij-idea, yeoman, jshint

I am using Intellij 12.1.6 for a web project generated by Yeoman. The project runs JSHint when files are updated and I get a lot of these warings:

> line 11  col 10  Expected 'restrict' to have an indentation at 9
>   instead at 10
>
> line 12  col 10  Expected 'scope' to have an indentation at 9 instead
>   at 10.
>
> line 14  col 10  Expected '}' to have an indentation at 11 instead at
>   10.

My js files are formatted using the default settings in Intellij. Any suggestions on what I should do to get this working?

Comment: Is JSHint validation enabled in your Settings?

Comment: Yes, and IntelliJ gives me the same error message.

Comment: this problem usually appears when there are unnecessary spaces in your code, so you manually remove the spaces or press Ctrl + Alt + L (in Windows) and automatically format the file. Anyway, these are just warnings :)

Answer (score 2):

Using IntelliJ WebStorm these errors are fixed by using the latest version of JSHint in WS - v2.5.1.

I've just moved to using IntilliJ IDEA instead but the max version is 2.4.4 which shows the same errors you describe.  Unfortunately I can't find any way to upgrade the version used.  http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/jshint.html says:

> IntelliJ IDEA comes bundled with version 1.0.0, which is used by
>   default. IntelliJ IDEA provides the ability to download another
>   version, which is not bundled. Actually, the alternative version is
>   downloaded only once, whereupon it is available without download.

However I cannot see how this is done and can't find any further help on this.  I'm going to continue searching and if no success I'll be back to ask the question here.  Maybe you can save it into a directory ...

**UPDATE - worked it out**

Based on http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/preparing-to-use-karma-test-runner.html "Installing the Karma test runner globally" (see these instructions for how to do using alternate means such as the command-line)-

- Go to Settings > Project Setttings (section) > Node.js & NPM
- Setup the sources (it should pull down a list of available packages for NPM to install)
- hit the green '+'
- enter 'jshint' into the search box at the top
- choose the latest version (2.5.1 as of this date 12/6/14)
- enter '-g' into the options to install globally
- hit 'install package'
- Close the 'Available Packages' dialog
- Enter 'jshint' into the Settings search box up the top
- Choose the version

Interestingly, although the package manager said it installed JSHint 2.5.1, in the versions menu is 2.5.0.  I went with it as it solved the problems (red squigly with 'indentation' errors etc...).

Comment: Great information, thank you for that. My solution is to disable jshint but that does not feel optimal. Please post back here if you find anything useful.

Comment: Ok its installed as a Plugin.  Exactly like what is described at http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/preparing-to-use-karma-test-runner.html for installing Karma.

Comment: In a fact JSHint version dropdown list is built using http://download.jetbrains.com/idea/jshint/versions.json. There were some network problems, so '2.5.1' version wasn't available. Now it's in the list.

Answer (score 0):

**Verified with version 2022.2.1**

go to:

MacOs : `~/Library/Caches/JetBrains/<product><version>/javascript/jshint`
Linux : `~/.cache/JetBrains/<product><version>/javascript/jshint`
Windows : `%LOCALAPPDATA%\JetBrains\<product><version>\javascript\jshint`

*[source](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/directories-used-by-the-ide-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs.html#c5a50aef)*

Save there file named `jshint-<version>.js`
go to your project's directory `.idea` and open `jsLinters/jshint.xml` change `version` attribute there to desired one and restart IDE.